# display selected from dropdown box in a form as readonly

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a  situation, ie, I wanted the selected data from the dropdown box to be displayed inside a form (of type text) below it and which should be readonly.(using html/javascript). I am not able to do that as i am a pioneer in that
Hope responses

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: where is your code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a select list like below (notice the onchange event handler)

```
<select onchange="fillTextBox(this)" id='mySelectList'>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

You will also need a text box (lets give it an Id `myTextBox`)

```
<input value='' name='' id='myTextBox'></input>
```

You'll need the following script for `fillTextBox` function

```
function fillTextBox(obj) {
    var sel = obj.value;
    document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = sel;   
}
```

Comment: This would require server side logic (sessions) or client side logic ([cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) )

Comment: Salaam bhai,, That might be tougher?? This is my 1st page and i was told to make such things in the page by my employer.. so I may have to go with it???

Answer (score 1):

The below is a rough sketch of a non-jquery method of dynamically changing one form box using input from a dropdown menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function optionCallBack (arg) {
                var currentOption = arg.options[arg.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById('changeForm').value = currentOption;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select onclick="optionCallBack(this)" id='getForm'>
          <option>asia</option>
          <option>africa</option>
          <option>america</option>
          <option>europe</option>
        </select>
        <form>
            <input value='europe' name='changeForm' id='changeForm'></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u sir,,    Now I have 1 more question, ie, if we load the same url after selecting one from the dropdown, the fields again changes and goes to the initial state , right? So is there any solution for that? that means say if i select africa, it should be africa thereafter

Comment: Are you using PHP? if so, you can add to the `optionCallBack()` script the following: `$('#getForm').load('cookieScript.php',{'options[]':[currentOption]});` then in a separate PHP script gather `$_POST['options']` into variable (say `$options`) and set a cookie via `setcookie("country",$option, time()+60*60*24*30,"/")`. You can then define a costant to be that cookie's value (`define('COUNTRY', $_COOKIE['country'])`) at the beginning of the script and in the html have `<input value='<? echo COUNTRY ?>'>`, assuming its inside a PHP script. I can elaborated in an edited answer if needed.